# Global Subversion SSH config in Windows / Checking out Subversion project as SYSTEM on Windows

Tags: windows, svn, ssh, windows-server-2003

I'm trying to set up a scheduled Subversion commit from Windows Server 2003 machine over SVN+SSH as a task. I'd like the commit script to be executed as SYSTEM-user. So I'm guessing, for that to work I need to check-out the repository as SYSTEM, too - but am unable to achieve it so far.

I'm already able to achieve the above with my own user over SSH. I've done the following:

1. I added a [tunnels] entity in my local subversion configuration:

   ssh = plink.exe -i "C:/Keys/my_key.ppk"
2. Added the key to the `authorized_keys` file on the server running Subversion
3. I checked out the repository with a script as below:

   svn co svn+ssh://user@server/path/to/repo/ C:\Local\Project\Path

I'd now like to reproduce the above steps for SYSTEM user, to be able to run a scheduled commit later. The problem I'm facing is I don't know how to check out the repository as SYSTEM, because:

1. I don't know the syntax to use to check out a repository as SYSTEM
2. I don't know where the global (or SYSTEM's) Subversion config is stored on a Windows Server 2003. I've already tried: `C:\Documents and Settings\Default User\Application Data\Subversion` and `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\Subversion`, but without success.

I also read somewhere I possibly could use `svn switch` for what I want, but wouldn't know how to `svn switch` as SYSTEM. I also considered writing scripts for svn check-out or switch and running them as SYSTEM, but then I still need global SVN config to add `my_key.ppk`, too.

I hope the above description is clear enough. I've been struggling with it for a long time now and am having problems summarizing it myself. Any hints appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why you would need to checkout as SYSTEM only to be able to commit as SYSTEM.  ssh user names (user@server) don't need to match Windows' user names, IMHO.  The only thing that SYSTEM needs is read/write access to the working copy.

Comment: Windows SYSTEM user has all the necessary rights. The point is, I don't know how to set [tunnels] configuration for SYSTEM user in Windows Server 2003 to be able to use SVN+SSH authentication in command-line. Regarding your first statement: I also don't see why I would need to checkout as SYSTEM to commit as SYSTEM, but this seems to be the case with Subversion SVN+SSH. Or I just don't know the right syntax, as stated in the question.

Answer (score 2):

As a side, that doesn't seem to be totally off-topic: https://serverfault.com/q/9325/122307

This is not a real answer to your question, yet it might solve your problem: Why not use `svn <command> --config-dir ARG` or `svn <command> --config-option ARG`?

You could specify the config file/option like this, thus being able to set [tunnels].

Answer (score 0):

@cxxl **really answered** on question, when mentioned `--config-dir`. I'll just try to shed some light on problem

> I'm guessing, for that to work I need to check-out the repository as SYSTEM

Wrong and bad guessing, because **stored locally user's auth data** doesn't used in case of SSH-auth, for ssh remote authentication performed. Per-user auth-dir

```
\%AppData%\Subversion\auth>dir /W
...
[svn.simple]                [svn.ssl.client-passphrase]
[svn.ssl.server]            [svn.username]
...
```

contain **stored credentials only** for http|https|svn and cert-based client authentication, and **nothing** for ssh-related repositories

I.e your executed under LSA script must be able to
* read Working Copy files (checkouted under *any other* real local user), maybe write (can't recall requirement for .svn dir permissions)
* read and, thus, use predefined and fine-tuned Subversion's config files (tunnel section), which can be config of any other user

PS: `swn switch` change linked URL of repository for Working Copy and have nothing common with users